# LiveCD customization of Ubuntu 13.04/13.10: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system""

Tags: boot, 13.10, live-cd, iso, customization

Hello

I've followed this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization and when I boot my iso it appears a BusyBox showing this message: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"" (/var/log/casper.log contains the same). I think the reason is that guide is obsolete. What a pitty!!

Could you show me some light about what can I do to try to solve this problem? I'm really stuck. Thanks, thanks, thanks a lot

P.S: I do not want to use Ubuntu-Builder or similar, because I want to learn how to do it "by hand"

Comment: That guide looks to be still valid for 2 things that have become old: the ISO mentioned and the part about gconf. The 1st is solved by using a newer one and changing the commands to the new one. The 2nd requires usage of dconf or other methods. But most of it still is valid ;)

Comment: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system" might mean you need to change your SATA controller type from IDE to AHCI in your BIOS. It can also be a wrong md5hash ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM ) It might not be related to that wiki page ;)

Comment: Well, I'm testing the iso with VirtualBox. I've tried putting both the CD unit and a VDI hard disk too inside the IDE controller mode, and nothing. I've tried putting them inside a SATA -AHCI- controller mode, and nothing. The md5hash is done with this command (executed inside folder will become the iso): find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | grep -v "\./md5sum.txt" > md5sum.txt .Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've found the solution!

I must copy kernel+initrd from squashfs chroot to /casper folder instead of leaving kernel+initrd which are already present there.

This step appears in the guide, but it's presented as something "advanced" - and I guessed that it was "optional" too- under "Live CD kernel" section (belonging to "Advanced customizations" chapter).

Thanks to everyone